# how to save HTML in byte[] as Image??? c#

Tags: c#, image, byte

i have HTML page source of website saved as String in `string PageSource;` 
i need to save it in SQL Database as Image of type image.
How to convert `PageSource` in byte[] and save it as Image in database.

Comment: Are you trying to save an image of the rendered page to the database?

Comment: Do you want to make a picture of the website and save this picture or do you want to save the site's bytes in a in a picture field?

Comment: This is a hard problem if you are trying to parse the HTML and turn it into an image.  Most of the browsers do it, so you could look into using the renderer parts of Webkit or Firefox.

Comment: I assume the OP is talking about the `image` datatype not creating pictures. You should use `varbinary(max)` as `image` is deprecated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following code to convert a string to a byte array, which can then be saved in a database image field.

```
var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(htmlString);
```

Use of image will be deprecated, consider using varbinary(max).